# Installing RubyOnRails on a RedHat linux box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, redhat

Through VMWare cloud services all I am given is a RedHat machine with a login that I can only ssh to it with a command like `ssh root@10.123.34.4`
And my goal is to install Ruby,Rails on it.
Some Googling gave me this link: https://github.com/joshfng/railsready

so I copy-paste the command he has but this is the message I get: **"The script must be run as a normal user with sudo prigs**

What should I do at this point? Or if you have better ways on doing this even better.

[image]

Comment: Make yourself a user with `sudo` privileges? `useradd eric; usermod -a -G wheel eric`

Comment: will try it, I'm not a Linux guy sorry, haven't seen any of these commands in my life! :)

Comment: Didn't work...Doesn't get the password

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark, the next of commands you want to run are: `passwd eric` then set your password.  Then after that do `su eric` and type in your password (You won't be prompted for password since you're logged in as root), then start with the installation.

Comment: Given that you don't know anything about linux, you might be better off going with a Platform as a Service (PaaS) product, instead of just a VM.  They will set up the rails environment for you.  Look into Heroku or Engine Yard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **RVM** and it will be a matter of copy pasting a command and you are done.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

To install both Ruby and Rails: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

Comment: asking for username and password as it couldn't get the ruby binaries, may I know how to solve this issue?